# Proving f'(x) is measurable on I if d is lebesgue integrable on I and f'(x) exists almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

This question is from Tom Apostol Mathematical analysis and I am struck on how to prove this.

> Question: If f is lebesgue measurable on an open interval I and if f'(x) exists almost everywhere on I , prove that f' is measurable on I.

On I there exists {$s_n (x)$} of step functions  such that {$s_n (x)$} $\to f(x)$ .But I need to show that that there exists {$t_n(x)$ } of step functions such that {$t_n(x)$ } $\to f'(x)$. But I am not getting any ideas on how should I use existence of f'(x) for it/

Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x)=\lim \frac {f(x+\frac 1n) -f(x)} {1/n}$ a.e. and limit of a sequence of measurable functions is  measurable.